# Open source relationship mapping/visualization APIs?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, visualization, data-visualization

A local group is mapping the relationships between board members and various organizations around my town.  I am trying to help them get some visualizations together.

The visualizations focus on relationships between people and organizations eg who is on which boards and will be drawn dynamically.  I am assuming I will be generating XML via PHP or Perl in order to feed the map drawing engine.

I am hoping to find a mapping API/library like the one for

http://www.theyrule.net/  >  Popular Maps  > Amazon.com

Anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: You're looking for something flash based specifically?

Comment: PHP, Perl, AS...  If it can map these relationships I'll learn another language!

Comment: One more question sorry, are the relationships in a dataset that you're trying to map or you're manually building the map for publish on the web?

Comment: Thanks for asking, should've said- this is dynamic mapping.  I am expecting to generate XML to a map-making swf or other script and have the Organizations drawn with spokes out to all of their board members in last 5 years for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks promising!

http://code.google.com/p/canviz/

demo of CanVis:  http://www.ryandesign.com/canviz/

and CanViz or similar is under the HTML 5 hood of

http://wordvis.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://polygeek.com/4613_actionscript3_mapping-api-adobe-flash-platform

Comment: Those are geographic maps not relationship maps.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to map who was on the board of what place.